Error in bifurcating shapes for vase
I am trying to fix this error while printing this design for a base, when it splits it seems to be duplicating a line (it was done in Simplify3D), causing a thicker line to appear as shown on photo 1. Any ideas how it can be approached?
I'm working with Grasshopper and Simplify3D.



Is this extruding clay? What printer is this? Is the green line image from Simplify3D? Very cool designs BTW!

Hi Oscar! yes, its clay. The printer is wasp 40100 and the image is actually grasshopper, where we are making the model and trying to figure out a fix
